# How do I determine "Network Location" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking

In Windows 7 (and Vista I think), a network you're connected to is assigned to a "location" e.g. Home / Work or Public.

Is it possible to determine the current network location programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), you are able to get the same list of networks that Windows shows, by using `NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.All)`.

Then, there's a property named `Category` on each network which tells whether it is public or private (home / work). There seems to be no way to distinguish from 'home' and 'work' though.

Comment: That looks like the closest I'm going to get. Thanks.

Comment: Link appears to be down as of 12-28-2015