# How to findout which network the PC is connected now

Tags: c#, networking

I am writing an application in C# and one of the functionality requires to perform different actions based on network connected.

For example;
When PC connected to home network network cable perform MethodA
When PC connected to home network but Wifi then perform MethodB
When PC connected to Office network on building 1 then perform MethodC
When PC connected to Office network on building 2 then perform MethodD
When PC connected to Friends Home network perform MethodE

Here how do I distinguish between different networks?

Comment: Are those arbitrary networks, or do you know something about them, or about some of them?

Answer (score 0):

I would use some information about the network to figure this.  If you are on wireless you'll know that the wired nic doesn't have an IP.  Then based on the IP scheme you can make an inference of where you are at.  You're going to have to know some information about the network.

For example, if your work assigns you an IP in the subnet ranges `10.1.0.1-40` and your home network gives you `192.168.1.2-255` then you can use that information to dictate what your application does.

Unfortunately this is a pretty loose coupling and if the routing scheme changes then your application may break. I'd make this kind of setting configurable, where you create a config that maps ip schemes to "locations" and you use that as your basis of what you do.

If you have your networks mapped to locations in windows you can use the answer in this question to help [How do I determine "Network Location" in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895692/how-do-i-determine-network-location-in-net?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could reliably detect whether the machine is connected via wireless or cable to the local router.

However, going further than that I think you'll run into a lot of issues.

If they are on Vista or above you should be able to get the "name" of the network in use.  However, this would have to be properly configured AND not jacked with by the end user.

Barring that, you could certainly check the ip address range assigned to you... However that assumes building 1 and 2 issue different ranges and those ranges aren't the same as ones issued by the home network.  Further it's entirely likely that the home network and the friends house network are on the same internal range.

I'd say, your application is much better off asking the user what method to use or by giving them the name of the method or by asking some other type of question to give you a hint.